# Weird Null Exception when creating generic list

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception, generic-list

I have weird null ref exception happening in production environment.

> The Exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.'

Code:

```
public List<MyBasicClass> GetSomeStuff(Mappings mappings, string IDField)
{
     //next line causes the exception.
     **List<MyBasicClass> fixedStuff = null;**

     try
     {
          fixedStuff = new List<MyBasicClass>();
...
```

Just creating a new generic list causes error. Same thing when I create the list like this: `List<MyBasicClass> fixedStuff = new List<MyBasicClass>();`

All the project references should be fine, all the projects are built for x86 env. I can not reproduce this issue in test our dev environments. Any ideas? Where should I look next?

Comment: It's impossible that this line causes this exception. Most likely you have changed the source code since you deployed the version to production and the line numbers no longer line up.

Comment: Stack trace will be helpful.

Comment: I actually created a build where I just divided that initialization line to two different lines. Just to make sure which line is actually causing this error. I was also thinking that it is not possible. There must be wrong dll or something. But I was wrong.

Comment: StackTrace: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SomeInterface.SomeClass.GetSomeStuff(Mappings mappings, String IDField) 
in c:\Projects\trunk\...\SomeClass.cs:line 707

Comment: Our Admin found errors from Event log (Event ID: 1000): Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe version 10.2.1.0, time stamp 0x519dfea8 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0x00560449